# Did I scam myself an extra reputation point?

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I hit the rep cap today, and then downvoted a question.  Somebody upvoted one of my answers, so I was back at the cap again.  Then I removed my downvote - I'm still left with that +1 I got in the meantime.  I triggered a recalc, but it didn't change.  Something there doesn't seem right to me.

[image]

Edit: My total rep seems to have just gone down by one, but the reputation page and the summary I get by clicking my name at the top bar are still showing this extra one.

Comment: Was the downvote cast this UTC day?

Comment: Yes.  When it was showing, it was a red -1 right below the green +1.